# I need to reverse the order of LED colors in my board

Tags: c, pic18

I need to reverse the order of my LED colors into 'PORT D' from the original sequence in 'PORT B'.
My original colors in 'PORT B' are Blue, Purple, Green, Red, Yellow, Turquoise, White, and no color. Now I need to reverse the order in 'Port D'. I am having trouble in my while loop with the proper operation.

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <p18f4620.h>
#pragma config OSC = INTIO67
#pragma config WDT = OFF
#pragma config LVP = OFF
#pragma config BOREN = OFF

void Delay_One_Sec(){
for(int I=0; I <17000; I++);}

void main(){
TRISA = 0xff;
TRISB = 0x00;
TRISC = 0x00; 
TRISD = 0x00;
ADCON1 = 0x0f;

while (1)
{
    for(char i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
     PORTB = i;
     PORTD = i<<2;
     
     Delay_One_Sec();
     Delay_One_Sec();
    }
}
```

Comment: `PORTB` takes the values 0, 1, ..., 7, and you need `PORTD` to take the values 7, 6, ..., 0? If that is right, then bitshifting is not the answer.

Comment: Do I understand correctly writing the counter values like this `PORTB = i;` makes your LEDs show the listed sequence of colors. And you want to write the sequence of values so that the other port shows the colors in reverse order. Can you confirm that writing the same value will cause the same color on the other port? We do not know your hardware , keep that in mind. From your coding attempt `PORTD = i<<2;` we'd have to defer a very different hardware. Please epxlain your thinking of that line. It is after all not a random line which you just posted to have it "fixed" into being the solution.

Comment: Why not reverse your loop? `unsigned char i = 8; while (i--) { /* rest of loop */ }`? I don't have your board data-sheet or tech-reference, handy, but that would be my guess. Use `unsigned char` or `unit8_t` instead of `char` to prevent unwanted sign-extension if `char` is signed on your implementation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think OP implied a requirement that the first port should not change behaviour. Wise of you to put a finger on that lack of clarity.... ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch - lucky guess based on the microcontroller torment I have endured lately `:)`

Comment: Judging from OPs now deleted comment, I think they mistook your question for a solution proposal. @adabsurdum Wish they would answer it instead to add clarity.

Comment: @Yunnosch -- the deleted "_thanks for the feedback_" comment wasn't too enlightening. I posted a tentative solution; maybe OP will circle back....

Comment: No I deleted my comment because I saw other users reply back to my question and didn't want to sound rude thanking only one of you. But anyways thank you all for getting back to my question. Also, if I assigned ' PORTD= i -- ; ' what does it do , I see no change. I also tried reversing the loop but now I get compiling errors.

Comment: @LuisB -- what values should `PORTD` be taking?

Comment: @adabsurdum , PORTD should have no color, White,Turquoise,Yellow, Red, Green , purple , and blue in that specific order

Comment: @LuisB -- I mean, what _numerical_ values? The bottom line: does my solution below work for you if you replace `i << 2` with `7 - i`?

Comment: @adabsurdum there are no numerical values, I set up the microcontroller from my book's instructions along with a Pickit3 device and I am going off based of the common cathodes color changing. & yes it worked, I appreciate your help.

Comment: How can you say "there are no numerical values" if you use an int counter to get the colors, here `PORTB = i;`? What else, if not numerical values, do you see being used here to change something on the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate the sequences [0, 1, ..., 7] and [7, 6, ..., 0] together, just use arithmetic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int i=0; i < 8; i++) {
        int forward = i;
        int backward = 7 - i;
        printf("forward: %d, backward: %d\n", forward, backward);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./a.out 
forward: 0, backward: 7
forward: 1, backward: 6
forward: 2, backward: 5
forward: 3, backward: 4
forward: 4, backward: 3
forward: 5, backward: 2
forward: 6, backward: 1
forward: 7, backward: 0
```

Comment: I think this is answering before the question is clear. But I can also see it as an answer according to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Good enough for an upvote.

Comment: @Yunnosch -- thanks; I'll update or remove if OP comes back and says that I have misinterpreted the problem